# If $\,f^{7} $ is holomorphic, then $f$ is also holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity, analyticity

I need some help with this problem:

> Let $ \Omega $ be a complex domain, i.e., a connected and open non-empty subset of $ \mathbb{C} $. If $ f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C} $ is a continuous function and $ f^{7} $ is holomorphic on $ \Omega $, then $ f $ is also holomorphic on $ \Omega $.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the condition that it be continuous redundant?

Comment: @Shakespeare: You can have $f$ nonconstant with values in the $7^{\text{th}}$ roots of $1$.

Comment: @orangeskid neat...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me provide an elementary proof:

First of all, either $g=f^7$ is identically zero or its roots are isolated. In the first case $f\equiv 0$, and there is nothing to prove. So assume that the roots of $g$ (if any) are isolated.

We need to show that, for every $z_0\in\Omega$, the limit 
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} \tag{1}
$$
exists. But
$$
\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=\frac{f^7(z)-f^7(z_0)}{z-z_0}\cdot
\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{f^7(z)-f^7(z_0)}=\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}\cdot\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^6 f^k(z)\,f^{6-k}(z_0)}.
$$
Let $z_0\in\Omega$, such that $f(z_0)\ne 0$. This is equivalent to $g(z_0)\ne 0$, and as $f$ is continuous at $z_0$ (and non-vanishing in a neighborhood of it), then limit $(1)$ does exists as
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{g(z)-g(z_0)}{z-z_0}\cdot\frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^6 f^k(z)\,f^{6-k}(z_0)}
=\frac{g'(z_0)}{7f^6(z_0)}.
$$
So if $Z=\{z:f(z)=0\}$, then $f\in\mathcal H(\Omega\smallsetminus Z)$, and as $f\in C(\Omega)$, and each point $w$ in $Z$ is isolated, then it is an isolated singularity. But
as $f$ is continuous at $w$, then $w$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

Therefore, $f\in\mathcal H(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 9):

We may assume $\Omega$ connected.

Let $g(z)\colon = [f(z)]^7$, a holomorphic function. Let $N$ the set of zeroes of $g$. If $N$ has an  accumulation point  in $\Omega$ then $g$ is identical $0$ and so is $f$. 
Otherwise, the set $N$ is discrete ( it may have an accumulation point in $\partial \Omega$).

The set $\Omega \backslash N$ is open and connected. The function $g$ maps $\Omega \backslash N$  to $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$. Let $p \colon \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$, $p(z) = z^7$.

$p$ is a holomorphic covering . We have 
$$p\circ f = g$$
that is, $f$ is a lift of $g$. Moreover, $f$ is continuous. It is a general fact that any continuous lift of a  holomorphic map for a holomorphic covering is also holomorphic. We conclude that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega \backslash N$. The singularities $N$ are removable because $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$. So $f$ holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Obs: In fact it works with any nonconstant holomorphic function $\phi(z)$ instead of $z^7$. The problem can be treated locally in a similar way.

Comment: what is the definition of a "holomorphic covering" ?

Comment: A holomorphic map $p \colon U \to V$ so that for any point $y$ in $V$ there exist $V'$ open containing $y$ such that $f^{-1}(V') = U_1 \cup \ldots \cup U_m$ disjoint and $f_{|U_k} \colon U_k \to V'$ has a holomorphic inverse. Worth proving that   $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\to \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$, $z\mapsto z^m$ is a covering. (same $m$ will work -- use polar coordinates).

Answer (score 8):

Let $g(z):=f^7(z)$. If $g(z_0)\ne0$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$ and a holomorphic function $h:\>U\to{\mathbb C}$ with $g(z)=e^{h(z)}$ on $U$. We may assume that $U$ is so small that $|h(z)-h(z_0)|<1$ on $U$. Then there are exactly $7$ continuous functions $f_k:\>U\to {\mathbb C}$ with $f^7=g\restriction U$, namely the functions
$$f_k(z)=e^{2k\pi i/7}\>e^{h(z)/7}\qquad(0\leq k<7)\ ,$$
and $f\restriction U$ is one of them. Since all $f_k$ are holomorphic so is $f\restriction U$. It follows that $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega\setminus N$, where $N$ is the zero set of $g$. Since this set consists of isolated points (unless $g(z)\equiv0$), and $f$ is bounded in the neighborhood of each $z\in N$ it follows that $f$ is in fact holomorphic in all of $\Omega$.

Comment: Nice answer, Christian. I must shamefully admit that it took me a while to figure out why any continuous function $ f: U \to \mathbb{C} $ satisfying $ f^{7} = g|_{U} $ must be equal to one of the $ f_{k} $’s that you’ve defined. I’m guessing it’s because this is true pointwise. In other words, for each $ z \in U $, the set of $ 7 $-th roots of $ g(z) $ is precisely
$$
\{ e^{2 k \pi i / 7} e^{h(z) / 7} \mid k \in \{ 0,\ldots,6 \} \},
$$
and then any continuous patching of a $ 7 $-th root of $ g $ must correspond to exactly one value of $ k $, i.e., the value of $ k $ cannot vary with $ z $.

Comment: @Berrick Fillmore: Thank you for the comment. I was indeed sloppy in this point. See my edit: Now there can be now mingling of different roots.

Comment: Hi Christian. I guess you meant, “There can be NO mingling of different roots.” Anyway, I posted my own variant of your argument that deals with this root-mingling matter in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 7):

There is an easy proof if you assume the stronger statement that $f(z)$ is continuously differentiable, rather than just continuous. Indeed, $f(z)$ is holomorphic if and only if $df/d{\overline{z}} = 0$, and since $f(z)^7$ is holomorphic, $df/d{\overline{z}}\times f(z)^6 = 0$. Assume without loss of generality that $f(z)$ is not the zero function, so that it vanishes on a discrete subset $S$ of $\Omega$ (which is also the vanishing locus of the holomorphic function $f(z)^7$). On the complement of $S$ we can divide by $f(z)^6$, so we have $df/d{\overline{z}}=0$ on the complement of $S$. Since $S$ is discrete and $df/d{\overline{z}}$ is continous, then $df/d{\overline{z}}=0$ on all of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a topological variant of Christian’s elegant solution.

---

Let $ g \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} f^{7} $. As $ g $ is holomorphic on $ \Omega $, either (i) it is $ 0 $ everywhere on $ \Omega $ or (ii) its set of roots is an isolated subset of $ \Omega $. If Case (i) occurs, then we are done. Hence, suppose that we are in Case (ii).

Let $ \mathcal{Z} $ denote the (closed) set of roots of $ g $. For any point $ p \in \Omega \setminus \mathcal{Z} \neq \varnothing $, there exist

- a (sufficiently small) open disk $ D $ centered at $ p $ and contained in $ \Omega \setminus \mathcal{Z} $, and
- a holomorphic function $ h: D \to \mathbb{C} $ such that $ g|_{D} = e^{h} $.

Now, for each $ z \in D $, we must have
$$
f(z) \in \left\{ e^{2 \pi i k / 7} ~ e^{h(z) / 7} ~ \Big| ~ k \in \{ 0,\ldots,6 \} \right\}.
$$
This is because the right-hand side is precisely the set of all complex $ 7 $-th roots of $ g(z) $. This means that we have a function $ k: D \to \{ 0,\ldots,6 \} $ such that
$$
\forall z \in D: \quad
f(z) = e^{2 \pi i \cdot k(z) / 7} ~ e^{h(z) / 7}.
$$
We claim that $ k $ is locally constant on $ D $. Assume the contrary. Then there exists a $ q \in D $ such that $ k $ is not constant on any open neighborhood of $ q $. We can thus find a sequence $ (z_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ in $ D \setminus \{ q \} $ converging to $ q $ such that $ k(z_{n}) \neq k(q) $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $. By the Pigeonhole Principle, we can extract a subsequence $ (z_{n_{j}})_{j \in \mathbb{N}} $ such that all the $ k(z_{n_{j}}) $’s are equal to a single integer $ m \in \{ 0,\ldots,6 \} $. Then
\begin{align}
       0
& =    \lim_{j \to \infty} \left[ f(q) - f(z_{n_{j}}) \right] \quad
       (\text{As $ f $ is continuous.}) \\
& =    \lim_{j \to \infty} \left[
                           e^{2 \pi i \cdot k(q) / 7}         ~ e^{h(q) / 7} -
                           e^{2 \pi i \cdot k(z_{n_{j}}) / 7} ~ e^{h(z_{n_{j}}) / 7}
                           \right] \\
& =    e^{2 \pi i \cdot k(q) / 7} ~ e^{h(q) / 7} - e^{2 \pi i m / 7} ~ e^{h(q) / 7} \quad
       (\text{As $ h $ is continuous.}) \\
& =    \left[ e^{2 \pi i \cdot k(q) / 7} - e^{2 \pi i m / 7} \right] e^{h(q) / 7} \\
& \neq 0. \quad (\text{As $ m \neq k(q) $.})
\end{align}
We have a contradiction, so $ k $ must be locally constant on $ D $. As $ D $ is connected, $ k $ must be constant on $ D $. Consequently, $ f $ is a holomorphic function on $ D $. As $ p \in \Omega \setminus \mathcal{Z} $ is arbitrary, $ f $ is holomorphic on $ \Omega \setminus \mathcal{Z} $. (**Note:** Although holomorphicity has global consequences, it is a local property.) Finally, $ f $ is holomorphic on all of $ \Omega $ as it is continuous at each (isolated) root.

Answer (score -1):

There exist exactly $7$ holomorphic functions $g_0,...g_6$ such that $g_i^7=f^7$ (there are seven holomoprhic $7^{th}$ root functions which we can compose with $f^7$, or $7$ branches if you prefer). We need to show $f$ is equal to one of them. We know that everywhere it takes a value that is equal to one of the $7^{th}$ roots of $f^7$; Hence we can argue by continuity that its values lie on one of the branches only, and we are done.

Answer (score -1):

It's true. If the zeros of f have a limit point, then so is $f^7$, but $f^7$ is holomorphic, so $f^7$ is zero every where. If all zeros of f is isolated, we can apply the Cauchy-Riemann equation and use the chain rule to get $ f^6 \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}} = 0$. Thus $f$ is holomorphic at $z$ whenever $ z$ is not a zero of $f$. Since $f$ is continuous and its zeros are isolated, we know from the removable singularity theorem that $f$ is also holomorphic at these zeros.

Comment: you're assuming the function is differentiable

Comment: It is not a problem. Since f = ( f^7 )^(1/7), apply the usual chain rule for one variable to (partial f)/(partial x) you can see it is continuous at every point wherever f is not equal to 0.

Comment: you're assuming that $f$ is differentiable again when you write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Comment: No, because the differentiability of the composed function is one of the conclusions of the one variable chain rule.

Comment: Is $f$ your composed function? The operation "^(1/7)" is not well defined. I think you're assuming that it is, and that it is holomorphic, and that $f = {(f^7)}^{1/7}$. Then obviously there is nothing to show. So, I'm sorry to say there is no value to this answer imho.

Comment: It is true the operation "^(1/7)" is not defined in the whole plane, but for a point where f(z) is not equal to zero it is ALWAYS defined in a neighbourhood.

Comment: So what? You're not proving anything.